# How to use cv.pencilSketch method in Javascript. I know it works in Python, but it is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I want to make image processing tool, and I have used cv2.pencilSketch() method in python. However, in JavaScript, it is not a function.

How do I do it in JavaScript? In my browser. (OpenCV js CDN)?
[image]

If it is not a function, I would like to make it a function with my own image processing, but I need help.

Comment: please post TEXT, not images of that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, as of now, only a small subset of opencv is exposed to js.

you'll find the complete ['whitelist' here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/platforms/js/opencv_js.config.py#L150)

(and no, pencilSketch() is not included, so you cannot use it)

IF you're able to [build it locally](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/platforms/js/README.md), you could try to add the function to the photo section, and build your own.

and IF that works, please make a github PR with it, so others can profit from your effort !

Comment: I will try some more, and if I solve it, I will make a PR.
Really a good idea, thank you.